# Apache NiFi TLS failed to start

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi

I have tried to install NiFi toolkit to enable TLS. I followed instructions given [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/walkthroughs.html#securing-nifi-with-tls).

I followed the steps,using `localhost` and host as `sachith` but when I try to start NiFi again, I get following error.

> Bootstrap Config File: /home/sachith/nifi-1.9.2/conf/bootstrap.conf
> 16:59:23,949 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] -
> Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml] 16:59:23,950 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find
> resource [logback.groovy] 16:59:23,950 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource
> [logback.xml] at
> [file:/home/sachith/Documents/Projects/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/conf/logback.xml]
> 16:59:24,032 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug
> attribute not set 16:59:24,046 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan
> for changes in
> [file:/home/sachith/Documents/Projects/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/conf/logback.xml]
> 16:59:24,046 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting
> ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 30 seconds 16:59:24,049
> |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerContextListenerAction -
> Adding LoggerContextListener of type
> [ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator] to the object stack
> 16:59:24,062 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@48140564 -
> Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
> 16:59:24,062 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerContextListenerAction -
> Starting LoggerContextListener 16:59:24,062 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate
> appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
> 16:59:24,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction
>
> - Naming appender as [APP_FILE] 16:59:24,084 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@93122545 - Archive
>   files will be limited to [100 MB] each. 16:59:24,127 |-INFO in
>   c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@93122545 - No
>   compression will be used 16:59:24,128 |-INFO in
>   c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@93122545 - Will use
>   the pattern
>   /home/sachith/Documents/Projects/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/logs/nifi-app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log
>   for the active file 16:59:24,131 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@7c30a502 - The date
>   pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH' from file name pattern
>   '/home/sachith/Documents/Projects/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/logs/nifi-app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log'.

`nifi-app.log`

```
2020-06-26 09:27:50,296 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @186210ms
2020-06-26 09:27:50,297 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJwtAuthenticationProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authorizer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: Unable to locate configured Access Policy Provider: file-access-policy-provider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:666)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
```

Edit : After Andy's initial answer.

My `authorizers.xml`

```
<accessPolicyProvider>
      <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">file-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">CN=sachith, OU=NiFi</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
    <property name="Node Group"></property> 
</accessPolicyProvider>
```

```
 <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>file-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">CN=sachith, OU=NiFi</property>
</userGroupProvider>
```

Comment: There is no error shown there, please find an error from nifi-app.log

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided the complete log output, so there may be other issues here, but it looks like the problem is `nested exception is org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: Unable to locate configured Access Policy Provider: file-access-policy-provider`. Did you provide an `authorizers.xml` file which defines a [`FileAccessPolicyProvider`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#fileaccesspolicyprovider)?

Look specifically at Step 7 of the walkthrough guide you linked to.